# Where are these modules - "Views Slideshow: SingleFrame" & "Views Slideshow:ThumbnailHover"?

Tags: views, 6, paging, javascript

Were these integrated into some other modules? Cannot find a trace of them anywhere on drupal.org but they are used at many places, like in this tutorial: http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode42

Screenshot from the tutorial showing the Modules: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=0000d1a

Answer (score 1):

They are packed with the [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow) module.

> Views Slideshow can be used to create a slideshow of any content (not just images) that can appear in a View. Powered by jQuery, it is heavily customizable: you may choose slideshow settings for each View you create.

Comment: Are they explicitly packed or is the code merged? Inside Views Slideshow modules, I see only "Views Slideshow Cycle" in the "contrib" folder

Comment: In any case, my real problem is that I cannot see "thumbnail" option in views for 'Pager Type' when trying to create a slideshow

Answer (score 1):

This from a release outline for one of the 6.x versions:

Singleframe and Thumbnailhover have been combined into the Views Slideshow Cycle module. Singleframe and ThumbnailHover are still available, but are marked as legacy modules. They will be removed in the next major release. There is no migration path from singleframe/thumbnailhover to cycle.

See it here:

http://drupal.org/node/926932